# What is a word for an object which fills a slot?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, if I have a series of slots, and any number of those slots are filled, is there a generic word for that which fills a slot?

In a sentence: "I have distributed each _____ among the available slots".

The word "object" might work but I was wondering if there is a word for something that is more inherently tied to the idea of "a thing that fills a slot".

Comment: What's the context? What type of things and slots are you describing? (I could say *ball* or *vegetable*, but those would be wildly incorrect if neither of those things were being used.)

Comment: That's kind of my conundrum, there isn't really any further context. I'm writing a computer program to put generic objects, which could be anything, in a series of slots. But I wanted to avoid the word "object" since that already carries meaning in that context.

Comment: In linguistics, _filler_ is the generic term for what goes in a notional _slot_. In Turkish, [for instance](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Bayramlash.pdf), there are a number of suffix "slots" on nouns and verbs that can be "filled" with one of a number of morphemes. This "slot/filler" type of morphology is typical of agglutinative languages like Turkish, where most inflectional paradigms are one-dimensional.

It also has a special use in [Natural Language Processing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/slot-filler).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

item [noun] https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/item

> "I have distributed each item among the available slots".

however that may not work if the slot is for example a slot in time

If we are using a more abstract slot such as a diary, timetable or journal

> "I have distributed each entry among the available slots".

Comment: Item certainly works for my purposes, but that is an interesting caveat

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact that you have no context whatsoever, and that another answer here indicates two different words (*item* and *entry*), neither of which may be appropriate in every given context, the only word that can really apply for something so vague is one you already used in your question: [**thing**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thing):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> : an object or entity not precisely designated or capable of being designated
> // use this *thing*

So, while not wholly satisfying, the following is the only way of covering every conceivable possibility:

> "I have distributed each thing among the available slots."